# smart pointer in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, smart-pointers

I'm coding in C++, using Visual Studio as IDE.

I'm trying to use C++ smarts pointer, but I get the error:

```
error C2039: 'shared_ptr' : is not a member of 'std'
error C2039: 'unique_ptr' : is not a member of 'std'
```

I included:

```
#include <memory>
```

but it didn't fix the problem.

Can i use this features with Visual Studio 2008? Do i need to move to Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2):

`std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` are C++11 features, and are not supported by VS2008.

You can use [boost smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::tr1::shared_ptr in VS2008 and Required below items
1. include header memory
2. using namespace std::tr1;

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `std::tr1::shared_ptr` and `std::tr1::unique_ptr`